# Субменю в Joomla 3.10.3 выдает 404

Tags: menu, joomla3

Есть дерево меню Menu1 -> sub_menu | Menu2 | .....

Так вот при переходе на sub_menu видает 404 - Category not found. Но если sub_menu поставить выше:

Menu1| sub_menu | Menu2 | .....

все работает как надо и с тем же Alias и типом меню. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

При перемещении субменю на уровень выше в урле субменю пропадает первый сегмент (алиас родительского меню).

**Причинами проблемы могут быть:**

1. не включен ЧПУ;
2. некорректная настройка вебсервера (например нет .htaccess если используется вебсервер Apache);
3. некорректная работа роутера компонента, а конкретно метода parse();